# selecting zip codes issue with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL statement to fetch City, State and zipcodes for that city and state. My query should return only one state, City and list of zipcodes. I am not sure how to write one. I am not good @ Sql. It would be great if any one can help me.

My Table looks like

> City --------------------------State  ----------     Zipcode  ------------    County

```
Alpharetta        Georgia      30004         Fulton
Alpharetta        Georgia      30005         Fulton 
Alpharetta        Georgia      30007         Fulton
```

Comment: Ok, you're not good at SQL. Are you good at trying? What have you tried?

Comment: @Catcall      I tried this ---   select * from (
  select city, state, zipcode,
    rank() over (partition by city, state order by cnt desc) rank
  from (
    Select City, State, Zipcode, count(*) cnt
    From postaldata
    Group By City, State
  )
)
where rank = 1

Comment: You're making it a lot harder than you need to. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9169243/562459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  City, State, County,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Zipcode SEPARATOR ',') AS Zipcodes
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  <Whatever you have>
GROUP BY
  City, State
```

Comment: Wow this works perfectly @Eugen Rieck thanks for the great help

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?:

```
SELECT City,State,Zipcode
FROM my_table
WHERE City='Alpharetta' AND State='Georgia'
```

It will select all the zipcodes for Alpharetta, Georgia. You will get one row in your results for each zip code, and the corresponding City/State (ie 'Alpharetta' & 'Georgia').

Or if you meant you want something like this:

```
City        State      Zipcodes
Alpharetta Georgia 30004,30005,30007
.....
```

then you can try:

```
SELECT City, State, GROUP_CONCAT(Zipcode) AS Zipcodes
FROM my_table
GROUP BY City, State
```

(with optional `WHERE City='xxxxx' AND State='yyyyy'`).

[Docs for `GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: I was looking for the second option. Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

Statement would look like the following

```
SELECT "City", "State", "Zipcode"
FROM Table
WHERE "City" = 'CityName' AND "State" = 'StateName'
GROUP BY "City", "State"
```

This would give you them based on the city, state and zip code the grouping would make sure you are given more than one per row

Comment: this gives me rows with single match. I was looking for list of zipcodes for the given city and state.

Comment: Okay if you remove the group by then it should provide what you are looking for.